# Calculate absolute from percent change using pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I know how to calculate percent change from absolute using a pandas dataframe, using the following:

```
df_pctChange = df_absolute.pct_change()
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to calculate the inverse: using the initial row of `df_absolute` as the starting point, how do I calculate the absolute number from the percent change located in `df_pctChange`?

As an example, let's say that the initial row for the two columns in `df_absolute` are `548625` and `525980`, and the the `df_pctChange` is the following:

```
NaN         NaN
-0.004522   -0.000812
-0.009018    0.001385
-0.009292   -0.002438
```

How can I produce the content of `df_absolute`? It should look as follows:

```
 548625      525980 
 546144      525553 
 541219      526281 
 536190      524998
```

Comment: I think the reverse is relative, you could find even smaller numbers that can reproduce this... just my first thought since the reverse effect seems hard to do unless you have a key that says let's say 1% = 1000

Comment: I don't follow? I'm simply asking how to calculate (n-1)+((n-1)*m), where `n` represents an element in `df_absolute`, and `m` represents and element in `df_pcgChange`.

Comment: @BradSolomon - I explicitly stated that the initial row values of `df_absolute` would be used as the starting values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use the formula:

```
(1 + r).cumprod()
```

to get a cumulative growth factor.

Example:

```
>>> data
        0       1
0  548625  525980
1  546144  525553
2  541219  526281
3  536190  524998

>>> pctchg = data.pct_change()

>>> init = data.iloc[0]  # may want to use `data.iloc[0].copy()`
>>> res = (1 + pctchg).cumprod() * init
>>> res.iloc[0] = init
>>> res
          0         1
0  548625.0  525980.0
1  546144.0  525553.0
2  541219.0  526281.0
3  536190.0  524998.0
```

To confirm you worked backwards into the correct absolute figures:

```
>>> np.allclose(data, res)
True
```